# Proving an equivalent statement for the Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

In my metric space course, we were taught the Stone-Weierstrass theorem as follows

[image]

We were told however that the second condition ("A contains the constant functions") may be replaced by the condition "A contains the constant function 1". Is someone able to show me how this is possible, I cannot locate a proof of this fact. Thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: The first bullet point says "algebra" but the conditions given (in the absence of all scalars) are not equivalent to the usual definition of "algebra".  If you replace it with the first 4 words "$A$ is an algebra", then you can replace the second bullet point with "$A$ contains the constant $1$".  Maybe that is what was in the mind of the person telling you that.

Comment: "Algebra" means that whenever $f,g \in A$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $af+bg \in A$, no? It's a little stronger than what you currently have written there, I think.

Comment: I see your point, I never noticed the scalars were missing in the definition of algebra. If the scalars were there then the bullet saying A contains the constant functions could easily be replaced by A contains the constant function 1. These were class notes written by a prof so they may very well contain slight inconsistencies/errors. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider the algebra generated by the functions $1$ and $x+1$ on $[0, 1]$. This algebra separates points because it contains the function $x+1$, yet every function $f$ in this algebra satisfies $f(x)\geq 1$ (because the generators $1$ and $x+1$ do, and this property is preserved under multiplication and addition) and thus the algebra cannot approximate the continuous function $0$.